# JIRA application link token generation failure

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

We are trying to use the JIRA application link for creating the token. But we are getting the error as 400 response

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "generate_access_token.py", line 30, in 
>       request_token = oauth.fetch_request_token(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 284, in fetch_request_token
>       token = self._fetch_token(url, **request_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py", line 368, in _fetch_token
>       raise TokenRequestDenied(error % (r.status_code, r.text), r)
>   requests_oauthlib.oauth1_session.TokenRequestDenied: Token request failed with code 400, response was 'oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key&oauth_problem=parameter_absent'.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to explain that a value for `oauth_consumer_key` is not being passed.

The `parameter_absent` error means that you are not sending the required OAuth parameters to the actual endpoint.

Can you check if this is being passed correctly or if it is not being passed totally? Adding your code snippet should help others help you identify the issue quickly!

Hope this answers your question!